# Is present continuous appropiate here?

Tags: tense, verbs, present-continuous

Is the following sentence correct?

> He is just buying a gift for his mother.

I am not sure if it is all right to have that "just" there and this lead me to believe that maybe the tense is wrong.

Comment: In either sense ("only" or "right now") *just* is fine in this context.

Comment: Thank you ! The sense I wanted was "right now"

Answer (score 1):

Just means a time that is immediate before the present.it would have been appropiate to use " he has just bought a gift for his mother".just means very recently or immediate past.it is correct if you use right now

Comment: There is nothing incorrect about using just in *"He is just buying a gift for his mother"*.

Comment: So just means right now. did you justify the answer in the context of "right now".just means immediate past

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing "incorrect" about your sentence. Whether it is appropriate to use *just*, *right now*, or *at the moment* in that sentence depends on the context/style. If you are saying *"He is just buying a gift for his mother"* to someone in speech, then the sentence is fine, as noted by StoneyB.

> Dad: Where is your brother? What's taking him so long?
>
> Daughter: Relax dad! He will be out in a minute. He is just buying a gift for mom.